# What is difference between IBM MobileFirst Platform Application Center Console and MobileFirst Foundation V8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

What is the difference between IBM MobileFirst Platform Application Center Console and MobileFirst Foundation V8.0? Is it a separate console? I'm so confused when there are different screens in IBM MobileFirst Platform Application Center Console and there is no dashboard to deploy adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation** (formerly known as Worklight Foundation) is a platform for building mobile applications for the enterprise. It is a suite of tools and services available either on-premise or in the cloud, which enable you to rapidly build, administer, and monitor secure applications.

IBM Mobile Foundation:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNJXP/welcome.html

**The IBM MobileFirst Platform Application Center** is a repository of mobile applications similar to public app stores but focused on the needs of an organization or a team (private app store).
It works with IBM MobileFirst and non IBM MobileFirst apps, and supports any iOS, Android, BlackBerry 6 or 7, and Windows Phone 8 applications.

It can be used in different contexts:

- As an enterprise app store across an organization.
- During development to distribute applications within a team.

Distributing mobile applications with Application Center: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/6.3/moving-production/distributing-mobile-applications-application-center/

Answer (score 2):

MobileFirst Platform Application Center allows you to host your mobile applications and acts as app repository like any other public app store from Google or Apple. Application center doesn't allow application backend or management capabilities like deploying Adapter etc, for which you would need to use MobileFirst Foundation.

You can find more details about Application center [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/appcenter/)